# PHP Unexpected end of file

Tags: php, eof

I ran it trough multiple paranthesis/bracket checkers couldnt find anything wrong im lost :(

```
  function kepmentes(){
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
      $id= getid();
      $kep="kepek/" . $id . ".jpg";
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $kep);
      $sql =<<<EOF
            INSERT INTO Kepek (KepNev,TID) VALUES ('$kep', $id);
EOF;  
      $ret = $db->exec($sql);
      $db->close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us the exact error message you get

Comment: why you not using simple ` $sql ="INSERT INTO Kepek (KepNev,TID)VALUES ('$kep', $id);"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HEREDOC Returning unexpected end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061312/heredoc-returning-unexpected-end)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP using Gettext inside <<<EOF string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694327/php-using-gettext-inside-eof-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have some spaces after your heredoc closing identifier.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means
>   especially that the identifier may not be indented, and **there may not
>   be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon**.