# css onmouseover causing DOM error

Tags: css, onmouseover

I have a php generated HTML where I would like to add some css onmouseover functionality like below

```
<span id='".$id."' class='userInfo' onmouseover='hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')' onmouseout='hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')'>".$c["test"]."</span>
```

The javascript is not even added yet that if I mouseover I get the following error at the beginning of my DOM:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

EDIT: sorry if I was not clear enough but my code is PHP generated so I cannot use any double quote ? I tried and it breaks my page

Comment: The PHP is useless here. Show us the HTML *after* the PHP has been processed.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem, but if you're using single quotes for your HTML attributes then `event,'popupUserInfoDiv')` is going to break it.

Comment: sorry but Im not sure the html you are asking about ? safari shows me error on line 3 of my dom right before `<!DOCTYPE html5>`

Comment: @MCMXCII I have to use single quotes because this is inside PHP or is there an alternative ?

Comment: @jotyhista Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694327/php-using-gettext-inside-eof-string. you might benefit from using that format if you need the double quotes for PHP and the single quotes for HTML attributes.

Comment: @MCMXCII that did it thanks, had to wrap it in a variable; if you post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using double-quotes for your PHP string already and single-quotes for your HTML attributes, you won't be able to use single quotes for your JavaScript.

```
hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')
```

Convert your PHP string to a string block and that should free up your double-quotes, see below for an example of string-block.

```
<?php
    $str = <<<EOF
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p><?php echo _("World"); ?></p>
    EOF;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the call earlier.

```
onmouseover='hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')'
```

should be

```
onmouseover='hoverdiv(event,"popupUserInfoDiv")'
```

same with

```
onmouseout='hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')'
```

and

```
".$c["test"]."
```

Comment: Yea this works too, it's like mine but the other around... in fact it's better, more consistent, singles for all HTML attributes delimiters :)

Comment: Being so oldschool, I prefer the double-quotes for attributes, and singles for javascript innards. ;)

Comment: thank you and sorry if I was not clear enough but my code is PHP generated so I cannot use any double quote ? I tried and it breaks my page

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single and double quotes, like this:

```
<span id='".$id."' class='userInfo' onmouseover="hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')" onmouseout="hoverdiv(event,'popupUserInfoDiv')">".$c["test"]."</span>
```

Or else the parser gets confused.

In this case I have used doubles for the HTML attributes, and singles for the JS ones. It works.

Comment: The problem with this being that since the whole thing is being output by PHP, the double quotes you've used for the HTML attributes will then kill the PHP string.

Comment: It doesn't, you can "escape" the characters, like this: print("He said\"Hello\" to her");